# How can I prevent timeout error during CI checks in Foundry Code Repository?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

In Code Repository, CI check fails due to a timeout after 20 minutes as shown in the screen shot below, how can I increase the timeout period?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error log shows `Job section timed ou`t, can you open the the `ci.yml` file in the Code Repository root file (you might need to first toggle `Show hidden files and folders` option to see it), then replace the section where it says `JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx512mg` with `JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2g`.

[image]

Once done, try reloading the page and rebuilding the notebook.